# Saving Distinct Keys for Dict and adding values according in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**I would like to save the present sample data in dictionary format which is shown in the sample output. There may be various methods to do so. I would like to learn all methods**

**dict should be { months : total number of births in the same month}**

> Sample Data for working

`['year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births',
 '1994,1,1,6,8096',
 '1994,1,2,7,7772',
 '1994,1,31,1,10765',
 '1994,2,1,2,11755',
 '1994,2,2,3,11483',
 '1994,2,3,4,11523',
 '1994,2,27,7,8195',
 '1994,2,28,1,11091',
 '1994,3,29,2,12154',
 '1994,3,30,3,11540',
 '1994,3,31,4,11782',
 '1994,4,1,5,10630',
 '1994,4,2,6,8782'
 '1994,4,14,4,11709',
 '1994,4,15,5,11753',
 '1994,4,28,4,11527']`

> Sample Output Required
>   need {month : births} # births = total number of births for appropriate month.

`{
   1: 3232517,
   2: 3018140,
   3: 3322069,
   4: 3185314,
   5: 3350907,
   6: 3296530,
   7: 3498783,
   8: 3525858,
   9: 3439698,
   10: 3378814,
   11: 3171647,
   12: 3301860
}`
Help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Use a defaultdict with an integer default. Then you need to iterate through the data, splitting on a comma, and adding the last column to the relevant key in the dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(int)
for row in data[1:]:
    r = row.split(',')
    output[int(r[1])] += int(r[4])
```

Comment: Is that any other logical method without using any package/library.

Comment: There are no external packages here. `collections` is part of the standard library.

Comment: I need to know what all can be other similar possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data = ['year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births',
 '1994,1,1,6,8096',
 '1994,1,2,7,7772',
 '1994,1,31,1,10765',
 '1994,2,1,2,11755',
 '1994,2,2,3,11483',
 '1994,2,3,4,11523',
 '1994,2,27,7,8195',
 '1994,2,28,1,11091',
 '1994,3,29,2,12154',
 '1994,3,30,3,11540',
 '1994,3,31,4,11782',
 '1994,4,1,5,10630',
 '1994,4,2,6,8782',
 '1994,4,14,4,11709',
 '1994,4,15,5,11753',
 '1994,4,28,4,11527']

myDict = {}

for item in data[1:]:
  year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births = item.split(',')
  myDict[month] = myDict.get(month,0)+int(births)

print(myDict)
```

=======================================================

```
myDict = {}

for item in data[1:]:
  year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births = item.split(',')
  if month not in myDict:
    myDict[month] = 0 
  myDict[month] += int(births)
print(myDict)
```